# Duplicated Selenium Screenshots During Simultaneous Test Suite Execution

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, testng

Consider the following setup:

1)One Jenkins node `J` to run the Java code of your test suites.
2)Two test suites `a` & `b`.
3)Two Selenium Grids `A` & `B`.
4)One FTP server `F` hosting the screenshots in separate folders named uniquely for each execution, `aa` and `bb`.

Let's say we run two suites concurrently.
`J` runs suite `a` on grid `A` and should save screenshots in `f:\aa`.
`J` runs suite `b` on grid `B` and should save screenshots in `f:\bb`.

What actually happens: during the time that only suite `a` is running, screenshots for a are only saved in `f:\aa`. During the time that only suite `b` is running, screenshots are only saved in `f:\bb`. But during the time that both suites are running, screenshots for suite `a` are saved in *both* `f:\aa` *and* `f:\bb`, and vice versa.

There's nothing in the code that directly suggests why this would happen, but I can hazard a guess--that the `onTestFailure()` listener listens to all events occurring in the JVM on `J` at any given time, so the listener for `a` picks up failures happening in `b` and vice-versa.  But that doesn't quite answer why the `ITestResult` isn't correctly identifying the suite/output folder.

Two folders affected by this problem
(started at 5:04 and 5:06pm):

`f:\Smoke_chrome_2017-01-03-17-06-53_rnd_866/Smoke/screenshot`
`f:\Smoke_chrome_2017-01-03-17-04-37_rnd_444/Smoke/screenshot`

Is there a way to fix this to improve the results of simultaneous test execution?

Simplified version of our screenshot-saving code:

```
class TestCaseListener {   
    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        super.onTestFailure(result);
        TakesScreenshot driver = getDriver(~);
        File screenshot = driver.getScreenshotAs(FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File(getFilePath(result)));
    }

    private String getFilePath(ITestResult result) {
        String fileName = foo(result);
        String outputDirectory = result.getTestContext().getOutputDirectory() 
              +sep + SCREENSHOT_FOLDER;
        return outputDirectory  + sep + fileName;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Sample test suite XML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Smoke" parallel="methods" thread-count="28" configfailurepolicy="continue" preserve-order="true">
    <test name="Smoke">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="SMOKE" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="FooTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="~RetryListener"></listener>
        <listener class-name="~TestCaseListener"></listener>
        <listener class-name="~SuiteListener"></listener>
    </listeners>
</suite>
```

(I think the suites might all be named "smoke" inside their XML files.)

Comment: Why don't you call them smokeA and smokeB?

Comment: Would that fix it, though? Does TestNG failure listener trigger or not based on the name of the suite it's in?